# How to create context class in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 database first project. I have established database connection and all the .cs files are created for the tables. A context is created, but this does not show up in the dropdownlist while creating a controller. Am I doing something wrong?
Any additional information will be provided if required.

Comment: Are you talking about the Entity Framework DbContext? Your database first option should create a DbContext for you. Can you find it in the code generated by your edmx file?

Comment: Yes Entity Framework DbContext. But the context file does not appear in the list when creating the controller.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this question? If this community is here to help someone who is new to certain technology, then any type of question can be asked is what I thought. Thank you for the discouragement.

Comment: Thank you for encouragement/discouragement. I have figured out a way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you completed the following?

1. Right click on the model’s designer surface.
2. From the context menu, choose Add Code Generation Item.
3. In the Add New Item dialog that opens, select Code from the list of installed templates types on the left.
4. Choose the ADO.NET DbContext Generator then click the Add button.

The above is from Julie Lerman's guide; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

If you have, within your Controller, ensure that you have

`using NameofProject.Models;`

and to open tables from your database, create the entity:

`NameofProjectEntities DB = new NameofProjectEntities();`

The variable names will depend on how they are defined when you created the context files.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    public DataContext()
        : base("DataContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { set; get; }        
}
```

Here is an example for you.

You need to extend `DbContext`. For `Constructor`, "DataContext" string is the `ConnectionString` name in `web.config`.

`DbContext` has notion of `DbSet<T>` for presenting tables in databases.

The rest is API calls etc.

say you have a Index Controller the rest comes as follows.:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _db = new DataContext();
```

This is really simple. You can find lots of tutorials and videos.